# Symfony - Sonata "Admin service "app.admin.post" not found in admin pool."

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, sonata

I get the following error while trying to access the dashboard.

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Admin service "app.admin.post" not found in admin pool.")

I use this tutorial ""5.3.2. Using the config.yml"" and I have no idea why I have this error
https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/reference/dashboard.html

```
sonata_admin:
templates:
    dashboard: SonataAdminBundle:Core:dashboard.html.twig
dashboard:
    groups:
        app.admin.group.content:
            label: app.admin.group.content
            label_catalogue: AppBundle
            items:
                - app.admin.post

        app.admin.group.blog:
            items: ~
            item_adds:
                - sonata.admin.page
            roles: [ ROLE_ONE, ROLE_TWO ]

        app.admin.group.misc: ~
```

Comment: Yes, it works when i use only "5.3.1. Using the Admin service declaration' in app/config/services.yml  but the second way "5.3.2. Using the config.yml" doesn't work and i don't know why [link]https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/reference/dashboard.html[link]

Answer (score -1):

Did you declared the services following the same tutorial?

```
services:
    app.admin.post:
        class: AppBundle\Admin\PostAdmin
        tags:
            - name: sonata.admin
              manager_type: orm
              group: "app.admin.group.content"
              label: "app.admin.model.post"
              label_catalogue: "AppBundle"
        arguments:
            - ~
            - AppBundle\Entity\Post
            - ~
```

Remember that you have to declare them into app/config/services.yml or almost into your src/{whateverBundle}}/Resources/services.yml

Comment: If you are using `admin.yml` in Resources/config/ make sure this file is loaded in the DependencyInhecttion Extension

Comment: This problem (in my case) were caused by an odd trailing comma:
    name: sonata.admin,